# Possible to install and run WordPress website in subfolder?

Tags: wordpress

In my root of my domain I already have a website that I made on my own with PHP and HTML. Now I want to create a website with WordPress, and I just wonder if it's possible to install and run a WP website within a subfolder like www.example.com/wordpress ?

Or would there be problems with database tables for the WP site if it's not installed in root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. During the installation wordpress will find the right directory where you uploaded it and will work without any problem. You can also have more wordpress installation in different folders on the same database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely run WordPress from a subfolder.